# Is Anything Different Between HTTPS And HTTP Protocol?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, web

(other than secure sockets and the underlying transport protocol, I mean)

I'm trying to implement the most basic HTTP server in C# (specifically, I'm trying to get my program to create a local socket listening on http://localhost:nnnn where nnnn is a custom port number, that responds as if it were a secure web server).

I've got the basic communications code working, accepting connections, receiving requests and responding to GET. I know this works in principle because if I point my brower to my listening socket via standard HTTP, it all works and it happily displays the web page I return.

But if I try and connect using HTTPS (I use a different port number), it connects, accepts and even gets the GET request OK - but despite me returning a response, the browser seems to hang, as if it is waiting for something else - and yet I *receive* nothing else as far as I know (I'm still listening for connections, in case it decided to make other connections).

My response is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:4301
Date: <assume date is correctly formatted>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 52
Connection: Keep-Alive

<html><head></head><body>Hello, World!</body></html>
```

As I said, this works fine for standard HTTP - the browser accepts it. I tried to include the header items I thought it might insist on (I also tried Connection: Close and forcibly terminating the connection - in that case the browser shows a connection problem. The GET it sent specified Keep-Alive, so I returned to that).

Is there something I'm missing to get the browser to accept the response for HTTPS like it did for HTTP?

If it helps, the GET request I receive for the HTTPS case is:

```
GET /test.html?param1=Test HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:4301
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Also, I'm using a self-signed cert created using MAKECERT - I have to accept warnings and force the browser to continue to the page because of this, but the point is, it *does* eventually send the GET request.

Comment: Are you certain that your server code is executed when the request is made? If you attach and debug, does it actually do anything?

Also - you might have an issue with the port - while it's generally possible to get http traffic on almost any unused port - sometimes secure traffic will be restricted (that's patchy - but in our environment we have a corporate proxy that refuses to server https over any port other than 443 - causing issues for testing!)

Comment: Have you considered using Fiddler or WireShark to check the HTTPS traffic of another server?

Comment: @Andras - using breakpoints I can see it get as far as sending me the GET request, and I send the same reply back as I did for the non-secure version (via the SSL stream, of course, same way I received it). It never seems to send any further data (my handler for BeginRead() never fires again).

Comment: @weismat - I hadn't thought of that! I'll give it a bash. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, WireShark doesn't work on localhost, RawCap (which it suggested) seems to only log UDP, and although Fiddler helps, it doesn't quite give me enough to understand. I see 'tunnel' lines for both browser to my code and browser to standard secure web address, and it even shows a 200 (but it calls it Connection Established rather than OK for tunnelling). For a normal secure web address, it then magically receives another reply, a standard 200 OK.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh... embarrassing. Turns out I was sending my perfectly-formed response... on the wrong stream. I was sending it back on the standard NetworkStream object instead of the SslStream one. Funny how things work better when you code it properly {:v(